# updating source table on insert into using mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi all I have the following query which works nicely but i know need to add the unique id generated in the insert table to the destination table

```
insert into claims.third_party(tp_names,tp_insurer,tp_registration)
select c.tpnames,c.tpinsurers,c.tpregistration from claims as c;
```

so in other words i need to return the unique id and add it to the source table creating a foreign key link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LAST_INSERT_ID() to get the last auto increment value.

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

UPDATE:

Use ROW_COUNT() alongside LAST_INSERT_ID() and you will have the range of keys generated.

[LAST_INSERT_ID(), (LAST_INSERT_ID() + ROW_COUNT())]

Comment: true but that would only work for 1 record i am reading over 8000 and need it to automatically update the source table as it reads each one, have a feeling i need to use a foreach or something but have no clue on how to implement it

Comment: follwed the link you provided just in case and came across the following

Comment: Important

If you insert multiple rows using a single INSERT statement, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the value generated for the first inserted row only. The reason for this is to make it possible to reproduce easily the same INSERT statement against some other server.

Comment: Is one of the values you insert an unique identifier for the claim in the third_party table?  You can requery the table with those unique identifiers to get all the new keys generated on autoincrement.  Else you will have to programmatically do it one by one (going to be real slow).

Comment: btw, last_insert_id is the first value of the record set inserted.  You could with some math calculate the range of keys generated.

Comment: unfortunately the three columns passed to third_party are just seed data so no unique values at all

Comment: use row_count() with it

Comment: i suppose i could pass the source tables unique id and use that to query on

Comment: If you have an ID, then you can guarantee yourself what the new IDs are since you are running a query.  Otherwise you will have to depend upon math to determine the keys.  I would probably lean toward a new query, just depends on performance needs you have.  I would rather have the guarantee.

Comment: thank you, i am marking your answer as correct as it helped me on the right path